# Modify $PATH from configure.ac

Tags: autotools

I need add `/usr/lib64/qt5/bin` to `$PATH` in `configure.ac` where  `/usr/lib64/qt5/bin` is the result of:

```
pkg-config --variable=host_bins Qt5Core
```

What is the correct way?

From [1] it says "Searches $PATH and queries qmake" but qmake is not in default $PATH , because we may have qmake for qt4 and qmake for qt5, but it is in $PATH qmake-qt5 . How I make configure.ac find qmake for qt5 or qmake-qt5 ?

[1]
https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_have_qt.html

Comment: Are you trying to modify the user's PATH permanently? or just look for a program in that `host_bins` directory that you will then use inside the configure script?

Comment: no, we need it just when it is building

Answer (score 1):

> I need add `/usr/lib64/qt5/bin` to `$PATH` in `configure.ac` where
>   /usr/lib64/qt5/bin is the result of:
>
> ```
> pkg-config --variable=host_bins Qt5Core
> ```
>
> What is the correct way?

The `configure` program generated from `configure.ac` is a shell script.  It can put that directory in its own path, so that `AX_HAVE_QT` works correctly, via ordinary shell syntax.  You can express that directly in `configure.ac`.  There are third-party macros for using `pkg-config`, and something along those lines might be more portable for that bit, but the simplest approach would be something like this:

```
QT5BIN_PATH=$(pkg-config --variable=host_bins Qt5Core)
# ... check for error / validate result ...
PATH=${QT5BIN_PATH}:${PATH}
export PATH
```

You would want to do that before `AX_HAVE_QT`.

That will not modify the path for `make` and the commands it executes, but you will have the correct flags, and you will have full paths by which to run the various tools discovered by `AX_HAVE_QT`.  If you want to export the discovered path itself to `make` or to templated files built by `AC_CONFIG_FILES`, then you can additionally make `QT5BIN_PATH` an output variable:

```
AC_OUTPUT([QT5BIN_PATH])
```